# jquery not working on work network?

Tags: jquery, networking

I have the following code on my website to display weather info.  It has worked fine until recently.  It still works everywhere except when I am at work.  It doesn't work on my work pc or my phone when at work, but it works everywhere else.  It used to work when I was at work.  We have a sonic wall at work, but my pc is exempt from it.  I have other jquery on my site that is still working.  Any ideas?

```
<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   jQuery.ajax({
   url :     "http://api.wunderground.com/api//conditions/forecast/q/autoip.json",
   dataType : "jsonp",
   success : function(parsed_json) { 
   var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
   var feelslike = parsed_json['current_observation']['feelslike_f'];
   var forecast = parsed_json['forecast']['txt_forecast']['date'];
   jQuery('#wg1').append(temp_f + " feels like " + feelslike);
     }
    });
   });
   setInterval(function refreshWeather() {
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   jQuery.ajax({
   url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api//conditions/forecast/q/autoip.json",
   dataType : "jsonp",
   success : function(parsed_json) { 
   var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
   var feelslike = parsed_json['current_observation']['feelslike_f'];
   var forecast = parsed_json['forecast']['txt_forecast']['date'];
   jQuery('#wg1').html(temp_f + " feels like " + feelslike);
     }
    });
   });
   }, 900000);
</script>
```

Comment: In Chrome (or Firefox has some equivalent), open developer tools and look at the "network" and "console" tabs after refreshing the page. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didnt mention that before.  It reads:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp_f' of undefined

Comment: ok, Chrome Dev Tools gave the following.  Is this what I need to look for?

Comment: Object
response: Object
error: Object
features: Object
termsofService: "http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html"
version: "0.1"
__proto__: Object
__defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__() { [native code] }
__defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__() { [native code] }
__lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__() { [native code] }
__lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__() { [native code] }

Comment: constructor: function Object() { [native code] }
hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty() { [native code] }
isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf() { [native code] }
propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable() { [native code] }
toLocaleString: function toLocaleString() { [native code] }
toString: function toString() { [native code] }
valueOf: function valueOf() { [native code] }
get __proto__: function __proto__() { [native code] }
set __proto__: function __proto__() { [native code] }

Comment: __proto__: Object
__defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__() { [native code] }
__defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__() { [native code] }
__lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__() { [native code] }
__lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__() { [native code] }
constructor: function Object() { [native code] }
hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty() { [native code] }
isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf() { [native code] }
propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable() { [native code] }

Comment: toLocaleString: function toLocaleString() { [native code] }
toString: function toString() { [native code] }
valueOf: function valueOf() { [native code] }
get __proto__: function __proto__() { [native code] }
set __proto__: function __proto__() { [native code] }

Comment: Click the "network" tab, click the 3rd icon (looks like a funnel I guess?), then click "XHR" and refresh the page. Click on the entry that's coming from wunderground, then click on the preview/response tabs. Is it giving you back JSON data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment, it sounds like `parsed_json['current_observation']` is returning `undefined`, probably because `parse_json` isn't what your code expects it to be.

To troubleshoot, add a `console.log(parsed_json)` as the first line of your `success()` function and see what the output looks like. This way we can see what you're getting back from the server.

You can also try simply copying/pasting the URL into your browser window and looking at the JSON from there: http://api.wunderground.com/api//conditions/forecast/q/autoip.json

I'm guessing either 1) wunderground can't read your location and is sending back a JSON error, or some kind of JSON format that your code isn't expecting, or 2) your work is blocking the URL and you're getting nothing back or the HTML for an error page or something. You'll find out when you `console.log` the response and inspect it manually.

**Edit**: And if wunderground returns a consistent error format (check their API), you can make your code more robust by checking for that error in the response before trying to parse it.

Comment: Thanks James.  My work network isnt allowing the 'autoip' feature to work somehow.